# Simplifying the dot product

Tags: simplifying-expressions, products, dot

Why does the code

```
D[x.x, x] /. {1. x -> x, x .1 -> x}
```

gives `1.x+x.1`,

while

```
1. x + x .1 /. {1. x -> x, x .1 -> x}
```

returns `1.1 x`?

For info, this is in the context of trying to reproduce the derivative for a vector in the dot product, i.e.

$$\partial_{x_\mu} x \cdot x = 2 x_\mu \tag{1}$$

so the result that I would like to have is actually `2 x`

Comment: I just want to be sure here. When you write `1. x` Mathematica understand `1.` as a machine-precision number times $x$. Did you mean the dot product `1 .x`? (notice the space position). For instance, `D[x.x, x] /. {1 .x -> x, x. 1 -> x}` returns `2 x`.

Comment: @MarcoB Oh yes that was the problem... I cannot believe I didn't realize this is what was going on. Thank you and sorry for the dumb question :(